# How to support automatic login using session cookies with angular2 and nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, session-cookies, angular2-nativescript

I am implementing a android/ios application in `NativeScript` on `Angular2`. I would like to preserve login credential information over reboots and closing of the application. I have read that `application-settings` is preferred storage mechanism for credential tokens, however all of the examples operate on strings tokens returned from an API.

The authentication API I am developing against is providing a cookie with session ID, as it is also used for our web interface.

I can tell that this cookie is stored temporarily as I am able to perform authorized requests against the API after having logged in, however don't know where this content is being stored and how to make it persistent, the call being made simplifies to this:

```
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

    private http: HttpClient

    login(url, data) {
        this.http.post(url, data, {withCredentials: true})
            .then((result) => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)))
    }
```

I see that `post(...)` may be too high level, to retrieve session / cookie information. I expect that placing the resulting cookie into a storage system, and reloading it in an early boot service constructor should allow me to exit the application and start it up again.

First question, is am I thinking about this wrong? Does it make sense to use this style of authentication in a nativescript app? I see from @manoj 's comment that some of this process may not be supported, but I am not sure if my initial phrasing of questions contributed to their answer.

Second question, Is there another call I should be making? Where is the current cookie store? Can I set the current storage place to be persistent and delete on logout?

I am unsure if I am asking the right questions to address my problem, so any guidance is much appreciated.

[edit]

I thought I had found a way to at least inspect the session infromation, from my app. I have seen that I should be able to append session information to all requests using an `Interceptor.

```
@Injectable()
export class LogInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
private logger: Logger;
constructor(loggerService: LoggerService) {
        this.logger = loggerService.getLogger(this.constructor.name);
    }

    intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.logger.debug("ABC -> XYZ");
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug(JSON.stringify(req));
        }
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap(
                response => {
                    this.logger.debug("XYZ -> ABC");
                    this.logger.debug(
                        `Oh boy we got an answer :: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`
                    );
                },
                error => {
                    this.logger.debug("XYZ -> ABC");
                    this.logger.debug("Something might be burning back there");
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the responses don't actually contain the session information. Why am I ever able to make authenticated requests?

Comment: It's not possible to overwrite cookies at the moment, it's still an open feature request - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2424

Comment: @Manoj, is this to say that we need be using a different credential system?

Comment: Yes or there is also a possibility you could implement it yourself, for example setting up your own Cookie Handler and update cookies natively.

Comment: In order to implement this myself, I was hoping to use an `Interceptor` to extract session information, however it seems that session information is tripped out before my `Interceptors` are used. The updated post, shows my attempt to find the session information. 

I know that this information is at least temporarily stored in memory, as I am able to make requests directly after a login. I do not know where.

Comment: As I already mentioned, you will have to access the cookies natively. For Android, you will have to get the [default cookie manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieHandler.html#getDefault()) and retrieve the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to mimic the headers of the cookies as they were being passed through the nativescript calls. This is done using `HttpInterceptor` pattern. There was some confusion on my part, as the values in the header are loaded in a "lazy" way. Angular's use of the term "lazy" does not map to my understanding of the term, but effectively manifests as you must use `.get('target')` on headers, rather than `['target']`

An implementation of my solution is provided in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/probinso/ca759cf988d1709c443b030345542d3e)

This passes far more information, than is required for a successful call, as it copies all cookies. The only required cookies for a preserved session are the `rememberMe` and the `JSESSIONID`, at least against our `shiro` backend.